# jQuery find image by 'src' attribute - plain javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

By my own admission I have become quite a competent user of jQuery without much knowledge of the javascript that goes on behind it.

Just lately I have attempted to find a compromise when weighing up whether it is worth importing the jQuery framework for relatively small tasks. And as a learning exercise to attempt to a least think about how it could be achieved without jQuery.

I'm currently working on something where jQuery is not an option. (Large organisation with practices set in stone).

I am able to select an image using it's source with jQuery however could anyone explain how to do this in plain javaScript.

```
$('img[src*="pic.gif"]').hide();
```

Many thanks
Gary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
function findImagesByRegexp(regexp, parentNode) {
   var images = Array.prototype.slice.call((parentNode || document).getElementsByTagName('img'));
   var length = images.length;
   var ret = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      if(images[i].src.search(regexp) != -1) {
         ret.push(images[i]);
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just select all images on page and filter their src with regexp or string functions:

```
var imgs = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('img')),
    resultImgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i].src.indexOf('img.gif') !== -1) {
        resultImgs.push(imgs[i]);
    }
}
```

Take attention to `Array.prototype.slice.apply`. It converts `HTMLCollection` which is returned by `getElementsByTagName` to regular array. This will improve speed of your script hundreds times.

Comment: I think you meant to use `Array.prototype.slice.apply`

Comment: Yeah, fixed. Thanks. Works great now.

Answer (score 2):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    if (images[i].src == "pic.gif")
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```